# React-Native TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple is not function

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

when running app on simulator iOS 10.3 iPhone 6 , there is no problem with exception like this, but when running on real phone I am getting this exception:

```
_reactNative.TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple is not function. (In '_reactNative.TouchableNativeFeeedback.Ripple(_platform2.default.androidRippleColor)','_reactNative.TochableNativeFeedback.Ripple' is undefined)
```

This happend when I perform touch on this component:

```
<View style={styles.centerView}>
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touch} onPress={this.openCamera} >
        <Image
            source={require('assets/img/camera.png')}
            style={styles.cameraIcon}
         >

         </Image>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   <Text style={styles.text}>{translate.t('openCamera')}</Text>
</View>


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    centerView: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },

    cameraIcon: {
        width:'100%',
        height: '100%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',

    },

    touch: {
        width:'80%',
        height: '50%',
        marginBottom: 15,
        backgroundColor:"transparent"
    },

    text: {
        color: '#949494',
        width:'85%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: responsiveFontSize(3),
    },
});
```

and onPress is Actions.camera() call of **react-router-redux-flux**

This code is working on Android in debug and dist mode. This code is working on iOS simulator ,but is not working on device.

Can someone point me to what could be error?

Answer (score 0):

**TouchableNativeFeedback** 
A wrapper for making views respond properly to touches (**Android only**). On Android this component uses native state drawable to display touch feedback.

Use [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html) or [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html)